# How to start Midnight Commander in one panel mode?

Tags: command-line, midnight-commander

I want to start Midnight Commander in one panel mode.

I know I can toggle it on/off using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> but I want it to be in one panel mode from the start.

How can I do this? Is there a command line switch to enable it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual does not provide any command-line option to start Midnight Commander as single panel. However, there are two ways of doing it.

**First way**: It exploits the fact that MC does not auto save setup if you do not exit it using the "built-in" method of pressing F10 or the corresponding exit button on the key-bar.

Follow these steps:

1. Confirm you have *Auto save panels setup* option marked under *Panel Options*.
2. Toogle MC to single panel mode.
3. *Options > Save setup*.
4. Exit MC.

When you open it again, it should be in single-panel mode. Of course, if you happen to toggle to dual-panel and exit MC with F10, it will auto save setup and when you come back again it will be dual-panel. So you should kill MC by other means, for example, use your window manager close window shortcut. Or kill it with `xkill`. Or whatever.

**Second way**: You may verify that MC opens in single-panel if the file `~/.config/mc/panels.ini` contains `list_format=long` for both panels. Then, just write a script that replaces `list_format=(anything)` with `list_format=long` and launches MC.

On Linux, the BASH script is simply

```
 #!/bin/bash
 sed -i 's/list_format=.*/list_format=long/g' /home/(your_user)/.config/mc/panels.ini
 mc
```

You can then put it in `/usr/bin/` and run it whenever you want to start MC.